# Is $\pi: \mathcal{C}^\infty (M,N) \to \mathcal{C}^\infty (S,N)$, $\pi(f) = \left. f\right|_{S}$ a quocient map in the $\mathcal C^1$ topology?

Tags: functions, differential-topology

Let $M, N$ be smooth connected manifolds (without boundary), where $M$ is a compact manifold, so we can put a topology in the space $\mathcal C^\infty(M, N)$ using [$\mathcal{C}^1$ Whitney Topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitney_topologies).

Now, consider $S\subset M$ a compact submanifold of $M$ with boundary such that $\text{dim}S=\text{dim}M$, using the same process we can put a topology in $\mathcal C^\infty(S,N)$ using the $\mathcal{C}^1$ Whitney Topology. There is a natural continous projection of $\mathcal C^\infty(M, N)$ on $\mathcal C^\infty(S,N)$, definided by

\begin{align*}
\pi: \mathcal C^\infty(M, N) &\to \mathcal C^\infty(S,N)\\
f&\mapsto \left.f\right|_{S}.
\end{align*}

> **My Question:** Is $\pi$ an open map or at least a [quocient map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space_(topology)#Quotient_map)?

Comment: It is naturally identifiable with the quotient map for the equivalence relation on $C^\infty(M,N)$ given by $f \sim g$ if $f|_S = g|_S$.

Comment: I tried this identification. however, I was not able to show that these two topologies are the same.

Comment: It is hard to show that $\pi^{-1}(\pi (A) $ is open if $A $ is open. It require the existence of a weird extension property.

Comment: Is there a relation between the $C^1$ Whitney topology on $C^\infty(M,N)$ and the topology on $C^\infty(M,N)$ induced by the strong topology on $C^1(M,N)$? Are you interested in the case were $S$ has no boundary?

Comment: @AdamChalumeau I'm only interested in the case when $S$ is compact and $\text{dim}S=\text{dim}M$, so $S$ must have a boundary. Moreover, I did not know that there exists a topology in $\mathcal{C}^\infty (M, N)$ called "strong topology", so I don't know any relation between these two topologies.

Comment: @AdamChalumeau I think these two topologies are the same https://planetmath.org/mathcalcrtopologies .

Comment: @MatheusManzatto ok in this case I may have a (very) partial answer, I have to think about it a bit longer.

Comment: @MatheusManzatto have you looked in Morris W. Hirsh _Differential Topology_? Exercise 16 of the first section in chapter two on function spaces is related to your problem.

Comment: @AdamChalumeau I didn't know about this book. I'll take a look right now!

Comment: "Let $M,N$ be $\mathcal{C}^r$ manifolds. Let $V\subset M$ be an open set then
a) The restiction map $\delta: C^r(M,N)\to C^r(V,N)$, $\delta(f) = f|_V$ is continous for the weak topology, but not aways for the strong.
(b) $\delta$ is open for the strong topologies, but not always for the weak".

Since our $M$ is compact weak topology = strong topology, so I suppose that these are encouraging news.

Comment: @MatheusManzatto yes it's not exactly what you are looking for I think but proving this could be a good start!